# Spring Boot with Derby Rest API 404 Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, derby

created simple spring boot rest api with gradle build tool

```
package com.example.demosb;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemosbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemosbApplication.class, args);
    }   

}
```

my controller class

```
package com.example.demosb;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class demoSbController {
    
    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public ResponseEntity<String> welcome() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Welcome To demo !");
    }

}
```

dependencies in build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
runtimeOnly 'org.apache.derby:derby'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
```

on url : http://localhost:8888
a login page is shown where i provide username:user and password is the  , which leads to 404 error as there is no request mapping on path "/" that is ok

but for url : http://localhost:8888/welcome , still getting 404 error where expected is response entity json object with message : "Welcome To demo !"

Answer (score 1):

In dependencies added is JPA and Derby. Delete them and see if it works now. The connection to the database must be configured.

Comment: yes it worked, but I am looking for solution without removing any of the dependencies as derby will be used as in-memory db , jpa for hibernate like functionality, security to apply security to auth users only

Comment: Look at this https://springhow.com/derby-database-for-spring-boot/

Answer (score 0):

it worked for now, will be replying progress on this

in my build.gradle, excluded tomcat related dependency from spring-web dependency and from configurations.all task as wanted to use jetty as embedded server

```
...
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
{
   exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
...
configurations.all {
  exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
  exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat'
}
```